# Magento - Call to a member function getOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

When I go to my controller; http://test.local/index.php/integration/adminhtml_manageskumappings/index/

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptionArray() on a
>   non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Company\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Manageskumappings\Grid.php
>   on line 105

This is my code:

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('skumappings_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('integration');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Delete'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
        'confirm' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    // This is the erroring line #105 //
    $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('integration/status')->getOptionArray();

    array_unshift($statuses, array(
        'label' => '',
        'value' => ''
    ));
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Change status'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array(
            '_current' => true
        )),
        'additional' => array(
            'visibility' => array(
                'name' => 'status',
                'type' => 'select',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'label' => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Status'),
                'values' => $statuses
            )
        )
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

The singleton class I am trying to load (`Mage::getSingleton('integration/status')`) is located here: `app\code\local\Company\Integration\Model\Status.php`

and the contents are:

```
class Company_Integration_Model_Status extends Varien_Object
{
    const STATUS_ENABLED    = 1;
    const STATUS_DISABLED   = 2;

    static public function getOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            self::STATUS_ENABLED    => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Enabled'),
            self::STATUS_DISABLED   => Mage::helper('integration')->__('Disabled')
        );
    }
}
```

This was working before - code was taken out of [ModuleCreator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html) and modified with my own models/tables etc...; now it's no longer working. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

P.S. If I comment out that line that loads the `Status` class, the grid loads but the status column is empty/blank:

[image]

---

**Update**

Here's the Call Stack from error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8y6h.png

Here's my config.xml: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ATy2NnEL

Comment: First post updated. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ATy2NnEL

Comment: try using `$statuses = Mage::getSingleton('skumappings/status')->getOptionArray();`, if it works I'll post the answer why

Comment: it works :o - do tell why. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because the configuration in config.xml you set as "skumappings" the name of the node in:

```
<global>
        <models>
            <skumappings>
                <class>Company_Integration_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>skumappings_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </skumappings>
        </models>
</global>
```

so instead of calling:

```
$statuses = Mage::getSingleton('integration/status')->getOptionArray();
```

you need to call:

```
$statuses = Mage::getSingleton('skumappings/status')->getOptionArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have another similar query, if you are up for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242083/magento-adding-dropdown-sku-list-to-my-form